# How to evaluate and change the value of AngularJS expression in html file

Tags: html, angularjs

In the following code snippet, status is returning 0 or 1, but I would like to evaluate and display the word "New" whenever status is returning 0 and "Old" whenever log.status is returning 1.  How could I evaluate and change the value on client side?

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th> 
        </thead>
        <tr class="info" ng-repeat="log in vm.data>
            <td>{{log.Date | date}}</td>
            <td>{{log.Status}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out of the box solution is

```
{{ log.Status == 0 ? 'New' : 'Old'}}
```

Another way to do it is to create a small filter.

```
.filter('condition', function () {
    return function(input, trueValue, falseValue) {
        return input ? trueValue : falseValue;
    };
})
```

And then in your code

```
{{ log.Status | condition: 'Old' : 'New' }}
```